# How can I add the tangent line from Fun 2 to Fun 3 to this function?

Tags: coding-style

Question: I need to move the point Fun1 to 10 positions in the interval [-3,0), and have the drawing updated each time (including the tangent and intersection points).

I don't know how to add Fun2-Fun3 to the drawing. Is what is done on the bottom correct? The Manipulate function only shows the tangent line from fun 1 to fun 3

````
ClearAll[f, t, P, PO]
f[x_] := x^3
df[x_] = f'[x];
tan[x_, x0_] := f[x0] + df[x0] (x - x0)
NSolve[tan[x, 1.2] == f[x], x]
NSolve[tan[x, -2.4] == f[x], x]

(*these are the two tangent lines, this is what I want too show in my Manipulate function, the line Fun1Fun2 shows up but the line FUn2Fun3 doesnt*)
Module[{x, pts, names, offsets, ptlbls, arealbls}, x[0] = 1.2; 
 x[1] = -2.4; x[2] = 4.8;
 pts = {{x[0], f[x[0]]}, {x[1], f[x[1]]}, {x[2], f[x[2]]}};
 names = {"Fun1", "Fun2", "Fun3"};
 offsets = {{10, -10}, {10, -10}, {-15, 3}};
 ptlbls = MapThread[Text[#1, Offset[#2, #3]] &, {names, offsets, pts}];
 arealbls = {Text["A", Offset[{-20, 2}, (pts[[1]] + pts[[2]])/2]], 
   Text["B", Offset[{0, -35}, (pts[[2]] + pts[[3]])/2]]};
 Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], tan[x, x[0]], tan[x, x[1]]}, {x, -3, 5}, 
  Epilog -> {ptlbls, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]}, 
    arealbls}]]


ClearAll[f, t, P, PO]

f[x_] := x^3
t[x0_][x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0)


With[{x0 = 2}, 
 Plot[{f@x, t[x0]@x, ConditionalExpression[t[x0]@x, x <= x0]}, {x, -5,
    5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-80, 80}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, {None, LightBlue}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, f@# - t[x0]@# &}, Mesh -> {{x0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, Red], 
  DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, 
      Epilog -> 
       First@Cases[Normal@#, 
         p_Polygon :> 
          Text[Style[Column[{"area:", Area[p]}, Alignment -> Center], 
            14], RegionCentroid[p]], All]] &)]]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{f@x, t[x0]@x, 
   ConditionalExpression[t[x0]@x, -8 < x <= x0]}, {x, -8, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-220, 70}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, {None, LightBlue}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, f@# - t[x0]@# &}, Mesh -> {{x0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
  DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, 
      Epilog -> {Text[
           Style[Round[#, .1], 16, Black], #, {-1, 3/2}] & /@ 
         Cases[Normal@#, Point[x_] :> x, All][[;; 2]]}, 
      PlotLabel -> 
       Style[PromptForm["shaded area", 
         First@Cases[Normal@#, p_Polygon :> Area[p], All]], 
        20]] &)], {{x0, 2}, 0, 3, .1}]```
````

Comment: The code that you provided is incomplete and does not evaluate. Please provide working code.

Comment: hello! I just updated it a few seconds ago! Pleease let me know if it works, Thank you, and sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don' t understand what you are asking.

Your method of calculating the area is somewhat inaccurate.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := x^3
t[x0_][x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0)
```

The curves intersect when

```
Solve[f[x] == t[x0][x], x] // Union

(* {{x -> -2 x0}, {x -> x0}} *)
```

The area between the curves is

```
area[x0_ /; 0 <= x0 <= 3] := Area@ImplicitRegion[
    y <= f[x] && y >= t[x0][x] && -2 x0 <= x < x0, {x, y}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Tooltip /@ {ConditionalExpression[f@x, -2 x0 <= x <= x0], f@x, 
     ConditionalExpression[t[x0]@x, -2 x0 <= x <= x0], t[x0]@x}],
  {x, -8, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 5}, {-220, 70}},
  Frame -> True,
  Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, {None, LightBlue}}},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Dashed, ColorData[97][1]},
    ColorData[97][2], {Dashed, ColorData[97][2]}},
  ImageSize -> is,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.09],
  PlotLabel ->
   Style[StringForm["shaded area = ``", Round[area[x0], 0.01]], 20],
  Epilog -> {
    Text[Style[{#, Round[f@#, 0.1]}, 16], {#, f@#}, {-1, 3/2}] & /@ {-2 x0, 
      x0},
    Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[{#, f@#} & /@ {-2 x0, x0}]}],
 {{x0, 2}, 0, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Row[{
   Control[{{is, Medium, "ImageSize"}, {Medium, Large}}],
   Spacer[50],
   Button["Reset", x0 = 2]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: this is what I want to show in my Manipulate function, the line Fun1Fun2 shows up but the line Fun2Fun3 doesnt. For example in your graph Fun1Fun2 tangent line shows up, but not the tangent line for Fun2Fun3. How can I show this?